# How to make Flex Markers appear in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

I'm trying to use Flex Markers in Logic Pro X. They finally appeared on one audio track after a half an hour of experimentation and reading documentation (by accident, I discovered that I had to delete all the alternate takes), but another half hour of experimentation hasn't made them appear on a second track. Deleting all the alternate takes wasn't enough this time. The first one has options for Quantize, Q-Swing etc. in the Region pane, but the second one does not. All it has is "Flex and Follow", which is "on" like the other. Both have "Flex Time" set to "Polyphonic" in the edit pane at the bottom of the screen.

Is there any repeatable way to predictably force Flex Markers to appear in Logic Pro X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to hit the "Show/Hide Flex" button, which is next to the "Show/Hide Automation" button. The keyboard shortcut is Command-F.

Additionally, you don't need to delete all the alternate tracks, but you have to flex edit them each individually. If the tracks are packed, you will need to expand the take folder, and you will be able to flex edit each take.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. The Take Folder thing is working. Where are those two buttons located? I can’t find either one.

Comment: Along the top of the arrange window; to the right of the Edit, Functions, and View menus

Comment: The Arrange Window is the main window, right?

Comment: Yes, the window with all the audio and MIDI tracks that make up your session.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues turning on flex and nothing happens.

My solution:
I end up having to import the audio clip to a new track and then it works.